# service not started on BOOT COMPLETE

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a service that I would like to start on BOOT COMPLETE

when it is started , I have a toast message displayed.

my problem is that when the device boots up , the toast is displayed and is stuck on screen, and the service is not starting correctly.

however if I am trying to start my service through an activity , the service is starting well and the toast disappears after a few seconds correctly.

my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tfl.extprotocolservice"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.6" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name="com.tfl.extprotocolservice.ExtProtocolBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".ExtProtocolService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.tfl.extprotocolservice.ISetIpPort" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.tfl.extprotocolservice.IExtMessage" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
 <!-- 
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my broadcast receiver:

```
public class ExtProtocolBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    /* broadcast receiver to start on BOOT COMPLETE*/
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent StartServiceIntent=new Intent(context,ExtProtocolService.class);
        context.startService(StartServiceIntent);

    }

}
```

btw, the activity in the manifest is commented because I don't really need it , it was just to test starting the service from an activity.

Comment: What happens if you first start your app by launching it from the launcher, then reboot ? do the reboot triggers your service?

Comment: @HappyCactus unfortunately not . still the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your application has no activities, your `BroadcastReceiver` will never get called.

When you install an application, it is installed in the "stopped state". applications in "stopped state" do not get broadcast `Intent`s delivered to them.

In order to get your application out of "stopped state", the user must manually launch your application (at least once). In order to do this, you must offer him an `Activity` that he can use to start your application.

Once your application is no longer in "stopped state", Android will deliver broadcast `Intent`s to it. That is, until the user "force stops" your application.

If the user "force stops" your application, it will go back to "stopped state" and will no longer get the broadcast `Intent`s. Until the user manually starts your application again.

Comment: Here you go! This behaviour was added/changed in Android 3.1: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` then it restart the device.

You can try `<action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>`

After more research, I think it was the `fastboot mode` which will not broadcast BOOT_COMPLETE.

Comment: what do you mean by fastboot mode?

Comment: Fastboot has nothing to do with this issue, fasboot does not even start the Android OS. You are likely confusing it with 'quick boot'.

Answer (score -1):

Your service is filtering actions, but your intent doesn't provide any.
Fix with this:

```
StartServiceIntent.setAction("com.tfl.extprotocolservice.IExtMessage");
```